# Excel sheet writing JAVA with POI API

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am using following POI api to write on excel through java code

```
public static HSSFWorkbook sampleWorkbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
public static HSSFSheet sampleDataSheet = sampleWorkbook.createSheet("ABC");
```

It is working fine while running with Java Main method. But when i converted it into dao with servlet it is creating the sheet only once and after that its showing following exception

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The workbook already contains a sheet of this name
at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.createSheet(HSSFWorkbook.java:813)
at  com.SangamOne.ApnaKhata.dao.ExcelReportGenerator1.generateSimpleExcelReport(ExcelReportGenerator1.jav    a:309)
at com.SangamOne.ApnaKhata.dao.ExcelReportGenerator1.getDealerxls(ExcelReportGenerator1.java:95)
at com.SangamOne.ApnaKhata.Controller.Xlspass.doGet(Xlspass.java:29)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
 at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: don't make your workbook and sheet static. remove static keyword and then run

Comment: Remove static keyword while creating sheet...

Answer (score 3):

```
/*Just use the following check before creating a sheet:
XSSFSheet sheet;
XSSFWorkbook workBook (the workbook to hold the sheet having name sheetName)
*/

int sheetIndex = workBook.getSheetIndex(sheetName);
if(sheetIndex == -1){
    sheet = workBook.createSheet(sheetName);
}

/*
If sheet with the given name does not already exist in the workbook, it will return -1, else the position of sheet in the workbook.
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while (wb.getNumberOfSheets() > 1)
wb.removeSheetAt(0);
```

Use above code to remove sheet.

Answer (score -1):

I met this exception before.
but my case is something as shown below

workbook.createSheet("a name that is very very very very long which exceeded excel sheet name length limit more than 31 characters");

google "excel sheet name length".
Not sure if this is the same situation you're facing. Just hope it helps.

Thanks

Comment: While this may answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here.